# Chart.js no data displayed with predefined units

Tags: chart.js

I want to display values with predefined units. e.g.: 22.00B/s

The data structure looks like this:

```
['6.84KB/s', '4.49KB/s', '3.42KB/s']
```

But only such data are displayed:

```
['7.5', '4.3', '10.3']
```

How can I display such values?

3.42KB/s

(Without removing letters or special characters)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will need to use a category scale for this:

```js
const options = {
  type: 'bar',
  data: {
    labels: ["val1", "val2", "val3"],
    datasets: [{
      label: '# of Votes',
      data: ['6.84KB/s', '4.49KB/s', '3.42KB/s'],
      backgroundColor: 'pink'
    }]
  },
  options: {
    scales: {
      y: {
        type: 'category',
        labels: ['6.84KB/s', '4.49KB/s', '3.42KB/s'],
        reverse: true
      }
    }
  }
}

const ctx = document.getElementById('chartJSContainer').getContext('2d');
new Chart(ctx, options);
```

```html
<body>
  <canvas id="chartJSContainer" width="600" height="400"></canvas>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/3.8.2/chart.js"></script>
</body>
```